# Value not being stored in cookies

Tags: c#, cookies

I am having trouble having a value stored in cookies. For some reason it was working then it stopped. It is giving me a null exception. Even though when i have something put in the text box, i still get the exception.

Code for when the button is pressed and how cookie is set:

```
protected void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Information");


        cookie["First Name"] = firstTxt.Text;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        cookie["Last Name"] = lastTxt.Text;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);



    }
```

How cookie is called on second page

```
HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["Information"];


        infoLbl.Text = "The page you came from is called: " + PreviousPage.Title + "<br>";
        infoLbl.Text += "Your first name is: " + aCookie["First Name"] + "<br>";
        infoLbl.Text += "Your last name is: " + aCookie["Last Name"] + "<br>";
        infoLbl.Text += "The page has been loaded: " + count.ToString() + " times";
```

On the second page I receive a null exception on aCookie["First Name"]

Comment: I think setting cookie.Expired and calling Response.Cookies.Add twice on the same object is unneccessary, and might even cause problems. Where exactly are you getting the exception?

Comment: I am getting the exception when i try to call it on the second page at aCookie["First Name"]

Comment: Can you debug what aCookie.Values contains? Can you check with Fiddler or browser F12 what the cookies received and sent to the servers are?

Comment: @JanErikGunnar it is saying that the cookie that i requested is null. Therefore it leads me to believe that either the value isn't being stored on button click, or its clear value on button click

Comment: Can you check with Fiddler or browser F12 what the cookies received and sent to the servers are?

Comment: I don't have fiddler and F12 isn't showing me what was sent. It just shows the html code

Comment: Check Network analyzer (or such), look at the HTTP headers in the response from the load where you are setting the cookie, and the request where you are getting the cookie. The cookie should be included in the HTTP headers

Comment: Its not showing that anything is being sent

Comment: This is really just blowing my mind because it was working

Comment: Hmm... How do you redirect between the pages?

Comment: I have a postbackurl on my button

Comment: "Its not showing that anything is being sent" - do you mean you are not seeing any HTTP headers at all, or that specifically the cookie headers are missing?

Comment: yeah when debugging after i hit the submit button it does not show up in where the debugger lists the cookies

Comment: I copied all my code and recompiled it in a new website and it worked. So i don't know exactly what happened